# When you have a series of questions, should you capitalize the first letter of each question?

Tags: capitalization

When you have a series of questions, should you capitalize the first letter of each question?

Example:

> How should this strategy be developed? **how** can the political decision-makers and those who receive and deliver care be involved in order to obtain their support? **how** can a reliable and sustainable program be implemented?

Answer (score 5):

A sentence is terminated by a period ("full stop") ("."), a question mark ("?"), or an exclamation mark ("!"). What follows a question mark, therefore, whether a question or not, is a new sentence, which must start with a capital letter.

[End of sentence punctuation](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/end-sentence-punctuation/#targetText=End%20of%20Sentence%20Punctuation&targetText=You%20have%20three%20options%20for,%2C%20or%20a%20question%2C%20respectively.&targetText=An%20exclamation%20point%20is%20used%20to%20show%20excitement%20or%20emphasis.)